# AWS IAM login 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm logging into a range of AWS accounts, most of them with an IAM user. One of these accounts is on

https://888526203171.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

When I log into this screen and submit I get an error page: 400 Bad request

However, I have retained the email link when the IAM user was created, which is:

https://signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Fstate%3DhashArgs%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&AWSAccessKeyId=&ltAccess%20Key%20Removed%3E&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A015428540659%3Auser%2Fhomepage&SignatureVersion=2&Signature=fP9dnzSv7c%2BmeF9p2AafjqTjtZ%2Fg55Xr6q7kaEZFrHQ%3D&Timestamp=2013-03-25T22%3A01%3A50.755Z

When I go to the first link and then click on this link, the login works fine.

Is there anything missing in my IAM setup?

Comment: Both links work fine for me. Go into IAM and get the link for IAM users to log in again.

Comment: I've customised the link and still have the same problem

Comment: I've tested the url with an office neighbour and it works fine there, but both Chrome and Firefox browser exhibit the problem on my machine. Sounds like a network stack issue, I guess

Comment: Clear your browser cache

Comment: Have done most days. I had this issue for about 4 weeks now